# Show Custom Taxonomy like how Wordpress does categories

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type, taxonomy

Need some help please.

I need to create an archive for each of the custom taxonomies I've created and I can't work out where I'm going wrong.

The custom post type is:-
**single-spotlight.php**

1. I've created the custom post type in my functions.php and they all work, and display fine following their respective slugs.
   eg.
   **https://sitename.co.uk/spotlight/post-title/**
2. I've then created the custom Taxonomy for this post type and categorised the variables.
   **Thursday, Friday, Saturday and Sunday** within.
   Then for each individual post, ticked which days the posts should show up.

Using:-
**archive-spotlight.php**

3. The archive loops nicely through every post as expected following the slug path.
   **https://sitename.co.uk/spotlight/**
4. However I want an archive for each of the categorised days too, and was expecting to have a;-
   **taxonomy.php** **(I think ??)** template that would work exactly as **category.php** does in the normal Wordpress post loop, ecosystem.

To find the looped archives at:-
slug path.
**https://sitename.co.uk/spotlight/friday**
or
**https://sitename.co.uk/friday**

However I can not link to the archive for these days, and have tried creating multiple direct templates to do so (listed below) to pull the posts through without success.

```
archive-spotlight-friday.php
taxonomy.php
taxonomy-friday.php
```

A bit of advice would be most welcome, code below.
With thanks in advance.

```
// Spotlight Post
function custom_spotlight_post_type()
{  
$labels = array(
'name' => 'Spotlight',
'singular_name' => 'Spotlight',
'add_new' => 'Add A Spotlight',
'all_items' => 'All Spotlights',
'add_new_item' => 'New Spotlight',
'edit_item' => 'Edit Spotlight',
'new_item' => 'New Spotlight',
'view_items' => 'View The Spotlights',
'search_items' => 'Search Spotlight',
'not_found' => 'No Spotlights Found',
'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Spotlights Found In Trash',
'parent_item_colon' => '',
'menu_name' => 'Spotlight'
);
$args = array(
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'has_archive' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true, 
'capability_type' => 'post',
'hierarchical' => false,
'supports' => array(
'title',
'custom-fields',
'post-formats',
'revisions'
),
//'taxonomies' => array('category'),
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-tag'
);
register_post_type('spotlight', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'custom_spotlight_post_type');

// Spotlight Taxonomy
function custom_spotlight_taxonomy()
{
$labels = array(
'name' => 'Event Days',
'singular_name' => 'Event Day',
'search_items' => 'Search Event Days',
'all_items' => 'All Event Days',
'edit_item' => 'Edit Event Days',
'update_item' => 'Update Event Days',
'add_new_item' => 'Add A New Event Day',
'new_item_name' => 'New Event Day',
'menu_name' => 'Event Days'
);
$args = array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array(
'slug' => 'spotlight'
)  
);
register_taxonomy('spotlight', array('spotlight'), $args);
}
add_action('init', 'custom_spotlight_taxonomy');
```

Comment: How do you expect `/spotlight/friday` to work - when you are using the format `/spotlight/post-title/` for the individual posts already?

Comment: _“However I can not link to the archive for these days”_ - are you talking about figuring out the correct URL, or how to get it to apply the desired template now? If the former - have you tried following the “view” links from the backend?

Comment: Just like using; **category.php** in wordpress. When posts will show dependant on their respective category name. I was expecting the same to happen using  **taxonomy.php** and if I wanted a specific hierarchy I expected  **taxonomy-friday.php** to pick just this category type up.